# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver(log in closed testing)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-console

Received this error in log of closed testing eventhough i'm not using instant app library

**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.phenotype.UPDATE cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.instantapps.PhenotypeUpdateService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{15d773b u0a190 TRNB bg:+11m51s747ms idle change:uncached procs:4 seq(0,0,0)}**